# Angular 2 form does not register / capture select tag data into ngControl

Tags: html, forms, angular

I am using Angular 2 beta.9 to make a form - following guides to make a model driven style form using ngControl, and not ngModel. Input tags work, using ngControl, and capture data. Select tags show the options and click selections, but don't capture that data into ngControl. I've tried many variations, like bare select tags, Material Design selects, with Validation, no Validation, etc. Inputs log, but no select data gets logged into ngControl. What should change in select tags?

HTML - country and state are the same structure

```
<form [ngFormModel]="residenceForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(residenceForm.value)" #apartmentRentalForm="ngForm">
   <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="25">
      <label for="country">COUNTRY</label>
         <select [(value)]="residenceForm.country" #country="ngForm" [ngFormControl]="residenceForm.controls['country']">
            <option *ngFor="#country of countries" [value]="country.name">
              {{country.name}}
            </option>
         </select>
   </md-input-container>
```

Angular 2 Component

```
export class PostApartment4Rent {
  submitted = false;
  residenceForm: ControlGroup;

  constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.residenceForm = fb.group({
      'country': ['', Validators.required],
      'state': ['']
  });
  onSubmit(value: any): void {
    console.log('you submitted: ', value); //inputs show; no select data shows in log
  }
} //end of export class
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by patterning this off the [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/FormBuilder-class.html) documentation. Basically matching the bindings of the `ngControls` off the `ControlGroup`.

```
<form [ngFormModel]="residenceForm" 
   (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(residenceForm.value)" #apartmentRentalForm="ngForm">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="25">
      <label for="country">COUNTRY</label>
      <select ngControl='country'>
        <option *ngFor="#countryItem of countries">
          {{countryItem.name}}
        </option>
      </select>
    </md-input-container>
    <br/> Selected: {{residenceForm.value | json}}
</form>
```

Here's the full [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UqkfgWTWNmUWa3y2dOex?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks. Angular2 has 2 styles of forms - template driven, using ngModel and model driven, using ngControl. I'm trying to use the ngControl style, and should have said so. I'll edit it. From a tutorial - "Note that ngModel can still be used with model driven forms. Its just that the form value would be available in two different places: the view model and the ControlGroup, which could potentially lead to confusion." When I tried ngModel, as above, I got undefined, even though ngModel imports with ngControl via FORM_DIRECTIVES. I'm trying to get selects into ngControl.

Comment: I see now. I've updated my answer that should either get you there or should be in the ballpark.

Comment: Thanks. Results are confusing. The code, from 3/20, does not register country in the residenceForm.value JSON nor in the Console for controls.country.value. It shows " "  It is pristine though the select has been clicked and changed. After thrashing, I added - #selectOption (change)='residenceForm.country=selectOption.value' to the select tag. The controls.country.value and _pristine are the same " ", but Console now shows all the filled in variables from the data model, and country has a value. This says a select tag needs a function, but I can't find one to change controls.country. I tried

Comment: As of beta.14, this problem has gone away when the page loads in Chrome.  The problem still exists in Firefox, and an issue, #8030, has been posted to Angular2's github issues.